# Crontab error : Windows can not find the specified file

Tags: python, cron, cron-task

I am trying to use this example script to test crontab in python:

```
from crontab import CronTab

tab = CronTab(user='www',fake_tab='True')
cmd = '/var/www/pjr-env/bin/python /var/www/PRJ/job.py'
cron_job = tab.new(cmd)
cron_job.minute().every(5)
#writes content to crontab
tab.write()
print tab.render()
```

It returns with an error 'fake_tab' not defined. If i remove this parameter and call the function
like this:  CronTab(user='www'). I returns the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
tab = CronTab(user='www')
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\crontab.py", line 160, in __init__
self.read(tabfile)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\crontab.py", line 183, in read
p = sp.Popen(self._read_execute(), stdout=sp.PIPE)
File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 948, in _execute_child
startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Does any one know, what am I missing?

Comment: Does crontab work on Windows? From the module's page we can see that it is not compatible with Windows. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-crontab/

Comment: It says windows is supported for manual crons only. bw we are just testing it on windows. our actual files are on a linux server.

Comment: according to `https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-crontab/`, crontab is for linux only.
at the end check the platform..

Comment: @TrainofThought test it on linux because cron is a linux concept

Comment: K.. thanks for the quick responses. let me test it on linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that `Crontab` is a Unix/Linux concept. Not sure if it can work under windows. This [Page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-crontab/) says "Windows support works for manual crontabs only". Not sure what he means by that though.

Comment: Yeah don't understand this manual thing either. but let me test it on linux.

Answer (score 2):

As the author of python-crontab I can report that the documentation has been updated. It's clear ineffective given the number of people puzzled over what manual means.

If you do this:

```
mem_cron = CronTab(tab="""
  * * * * * command # comment
""")
```

You should have a memory only crontab. Same if you do a file as a crontab:

```
file_cron = CronTab(tabfile='filename.tab')
```

I'm always looking to improve the code and documentation, so please do email me.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I found to make `crontab` find my job was:

In `settings.py` (I'm using django) I defined these variables:

```
CRONTAB_EXECUTABLE='C:/Users/myuser/myvirtualenv/Lib/site-packages/django_crontab/crontab.py'
CRONTAB_DJANGO_PROJECT_NAME='myproject'
CRONTAB_DJANGO_MANAGE_PATH='C:/Users/myuser/myvirtualenv/myproject/manage.py'
CRONTAB_PYTHON_EXECUTABLE='C:/Users/myuser/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/pythonw.exe'
```

Pay attention to the slash. It must be leaned to the right or it causes a syntax error.

By this way `crontab` will find the job or whatever you are trying to execute. In my case I was trying:

```
C:\Users\bsi\mlearning3\src>python manage.py crontab add
```